# connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/lsb/lsb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

First of all I am a 100% newbie, so I'm not really even sure what to ask.

I'm trying to build a production environment on Ubuntu 12.04 for Django. I installed Nginx, uWSGI, Python, Django, etc. I followed this guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04.

I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error, and when I checked the `error.log` file I found this at the end:

```
2015/07/22 17:43:18 [crit] 23919#0: *3 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/lsb/lsb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 180.152.149.63, server: 115.159.36.162, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/ubuntu/lsb/lsb.sock:", host: "115.159.36.162:8000"
```

According to the guide, I created all the relevant files but I only have 1 project, and replaced all instance of `user` with `ubuntu`, and `firstproject` with `lsb`.

For the server block configuration file, I just used the server's IP address and port 8000. The one that's in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 115.159.36.162;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/lsb;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/ubuntu/lsb/lsb.sock;
    }
}
```

Besides this I pretty much followed the guide to the letter. I found a guy who said it was due to the problem of permissions with `uwsgi_params`, I used `sudo chown ubuntu uwsgi_params` but that didn't fix it either (I'm not even sure if that's the right command to use...).

In any case I don't even know what I don't know here. ANY suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**UPDATE** after Daniel Roseman's suggestions

I indeed never started `uwsgi`, but when I tried to do `sudo service uwsgi start`, I get an error saying `uwsgi: unrecognized service`. I then went back up the guide and saw that they suggested I run a uwsgi command right after I install it to test it:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/user/Env/firstsite --chdir /home/user/firstsite -w firstsite.wsgi
```

This command returned another error,

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Some websites say that this has to do with uwsgi not being able to find Python. I installed Python3.4 before, it's accessible when I type `python3.4` anywhere in the shell. Besides that I think there's also 2.7 installed and maybe 3.2 as well. Not really sure if this is relevant, and not sure how to help uwsgi "find" Python, or if that's even the problem.

Looking back, here's a list of things that I did differently from the guide (contradicting my previous "to the letter" claim) that might be relevant to the problem.

1. I installed python3.4, from this Felix Krull depository, mainly because when I tried to do the normal `sudo apt-get install python3` it gives me an error, so after I added the depository I did `sudo apt-get install python3.4`.
2. The pip I used isn't the `pip3` that all these sites keep saying, since, again, I can't seem to install pip3 at all. So what I ended up doing is I got this `get-pip.py` from pip's website, and executed it using `python3.4`.
3. On top of that, in the guide that says install python-dev, `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, I did instead `sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev`. This is something the guide says uwsgi needs, so I'm not sure if this is screwing things up.

Once again thanks for all the help Daniel!

Comment: Have you started uwsgi? Is it using that socket?

Comment: The guide had me create this `uwsgi.conf` file and put it into `/etc/init`, which supposedly auto-starts uwsgi.

Comment: No, you missed the line (just before the conclusion) where you do `sudo service uwsgi start`.

Comment: Per what you suggested I updated the question - now I'm running into problems that seem to prevent me from starting uwsgi (FYI thank you so much for helping me along!!!)

Comment: Can you show the exact command you used to install uswgi? I suspect you have installed it for Python2, not 3.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think the command I used was `sudo pip install uwsgi`, because when I type it in, I get this message, `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): uwsgi in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`. Does this also mean that I did install it for Python 3?

Comment: Oh also, I also tried out `sudo apt-get install uwsgi`, and here's what shows up at the end: `The following NEW packages will be installed: libjansson4 libpqm-5.1-0 libyam1-0-2 libzmq1 sqlite3 uwsgi uwsgi-core`. So this means I installed it with `pip` and not `apt-get` right? Also not really sure why these two things would not know about what the other one did....